# Handlebars js - assign color with true or false boolean email tables

Tags: javascript, html, email, boolean, handlebars.js

I am trying to assign a color using a true or false. 
If true, make red. if false, don't.

I have at the moment in my HTML template:

```
{{#if row1}}
{{#if row1.col1}}
   <td class="mobileSquares" width="100" height="100" align=" 
   {{{row1.col1.align}}}" valign="{{{row1.col1.valign}}}" 
   style="color:{{{assign color 'red' color=true}}}">1</td>
{{/if}}
```

{{/if}}

And in my json to alter my HTML:

```
"template": "hotspot_grid", {
 "row1": {
  "col1": {
    "valign": "middle",
    "align": "center",
    "color": true
    }
  }
}
```

The other 2 {{{}}} work. I'm just not sure how to put a conditional style in now. Tried lots of ways. 
Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
{{#if row1.col1}}
    <td class="mobileSquares" {{#if row1.col1.color}}style="color: red;"{{/if}}>1</td>
{{/if}}
```